# How to show same message on each site page using middleware

Tags: python-3.x, django-middleware, django-2.1

I am new to django and programming. I'm trying to make an ecommerce web site and I am stuck on the custom middleware. I am trying set up a message which will appear on each page of site.

I think the code is working because if I enter print("something") and refresh the browser "something" is in the terminal window.

```
middleware.py 
from .models import MarketingMessage
class DisplayMarketing:
    def __init__(self, get_response):
        self.get_response = get_response

    def __call__(self, request):
        response = self.get_response(request)
        return response

    def process_view(self, request, view_func, view_args, view_kwargs):
        try:
            request.session["marketing_message"] = MarketingMessage.objects.all()[0].message
        except:
            request.session["marketing_message"] = False

settings.py
MIDDLEWARE = [
...
    'marketing.middleware.DisplayMarketing',
]

base.html
{% if marketing_message %}
<div class="alert alert-top-message alert-dismissible" role="alert">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="alert">
    <span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
  </button>
  <div class="container">
    <h3> {{ marketing_message }} </h3>
  </div>
</div>
{% endif %}
```

I expect an alert message at the top of each page (Hello there)

Can anyone help?